# How to return value with finding by the key in JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON data object as following:

```
 {
"StoreList": Array[1][
    {
      "code": "S1",
      "name": "Store 1",
      "ProductList": Array[3][
        {
          "ProductId": "M01",
          "TypeList": Array[1][
            {
              "TypeId": "E1",
              "Expiredtime": Array[3][
                {
                  "screenName": "C02",
                  "time": "11"
                },
                {
                  "screenName": "C05",
                  "time": "55"
                },
                {
                  "screenName": "C05",
                  "time": "67"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ProductId": "M02",
          "TypeList": Array[2][
            {
              "TypeId": "E1",              
              "Expiredtime": Array[1][
                {
                  "screenName": "C02",
                  "time": "12"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "TypeId": "E2",              
              "Expiredtime": Array[1][
                {
                  "screenName": "C02",
                  "time": "89"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ProductId": "M03",
          "TypeList": Array[1][
            {
              "TypeId": "E3",            
              "Expiredtime": Array[3][
                {
                  "screenName": "C03",
                  "time": "87"
                },
                {
                  "screenName": "C05",
                  "time": "90"
                },
                {
                  "screenName": "C02",
                  "time": "78"
                },
              ]
            }
          ]
        }        
      ]      
     }
  ]
}
```

**Expected result:**

I want the group all the  "Expiredtime" values into one array. 
Instead of doing three to four times of **foreach** loops to get into the depth, any other fastest way to get the result? i am  also concern about the nested JSON is getting complicated later some time.
Too bad, array_key_exists() is not working on nested array.

```
[Expiredtime] => Array(
[0] => Array(
            [screenName] => 'C02'
            [time] => '11'
)

[1] => Array(
            [screenName] => 'C05'
            [time] => '55'
)

[2] => Array(
            [screenName] => 'C05'
            [time] => '67'
)

[3] => Array(
            [screenName] => 'C02'
            [time] => '12'
)

[4] => Array(
            [screenName] => 'C03'
            [time] => '87'
)

[5] => Array(
            [screenName] => 'C05'
            [time] => '90'
)

[6] => Array(
            [screenName] => 'C02'
            [time] => '78'
)
```

)

Comment: use `json_decode()` and with loop you can fill it in other array.

Comment: that's my current solution, which i do not want to use too many loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column). There are still loops inside but on php side looks quite flat (not sure are there any more `StoreList` in json):

```
$decodedArray = json_decode($json, true);

$result = array_reduce(
    $decodedArray['StoreList'][0]['ProductList'], 
    function ($carry, $product) {
        if (isset($product['TypeList'])) {
            $expiredTime = array_column($product['TypeList'], 'Expiredtime'); 
            $expiredTimeFlatten = array_reduce($expiredTime, 'array_merge', array());
            $carry = array_merge($carry, $expiredTimeFlatten);
        }
        return $carry;
    },
    []
);
```

But it less readable than than OOP solution and looks like magic.

Comment: Ya, it is less readable, but the result is just like u said... works like a magic. XD Thanks anyway.

Comment: and yes, the no of store will be +/-.